# Получить данные из базы ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеется две модели Verse с полями(:locale, :book_number, :chapter, :verse, text) & Book с полями(:locale, :book_number, :short_name, :long_name)
Как можно получить каждую книгу с соответствующим :locale, :chapter, :verse, :text? Буду весьма признателен за любую подсказку, не пинайте сильно, только начал учит программирование.

Comment: А как между собой связаны эти модели? Как они вообще соотносятся?

Comment: еще нету никакой связи, хотелось бы узнать ка правильно сделать связь между двумя моделями. И в первом, и во втором модели присутствует поле book_number, подскажите как правильно сделать связь

Comment: Тогда рассказывайте, как они между собой соотносятся? Какая логика вообще за этими двумя моделями лежит? Почему у них именно такие поля и можете ли вы что-то изменить? И что такое `book_number` - это какой-то артикул, который вам надо хранить в базе?